# Rails: form_for remote not triggering ajax javascript

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to do an ajax request on a form_for. Just simply whenever a message is sent but right now the javascript is not triggering.

Could it possible be the file location since I'm using a partial?

**/layouts/_message.haml**

```
  = form_for @message, :remote => true do |f|
    = f.text_field :body
    %button{name: "commit", type: "submit"}
      send
```

**messages controller:**

```
  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    if @message.create
      flash[:success] = 'Message sent!'
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Message was not sent!'
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
```

**/messages/show.haml**

```
.chat
  - @convo.each do |convo|
    = convo.body
= render "layouts/message"
```

**/messages/create.js.erb**

```
$(".chat").append("Test append");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Turns out my app was sending my layout file. So i just did render :layout -> false

```
  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    @message.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {
          flash[:success] = 'Message sent!'
          redirect_to message_path(id: params[:message][:username])}
        format.js {render :layout => false}
      end
  end
```